# How to find and replace words in a text with specific characters in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find and replace all hashtags from a spreadsheet column.

But the find&replace (Ctrl+H) isn't delivering fast enough results (I have to specifically type in "#Happy" to find and delete that one word)

For example ( I'm going to festival next week #happy with my family) -> I would like to remove the '#happy' from that cell while keeping the rest of the cell.

Comment: "the find&replace (Ctrl+H) doesn't work " -- what does that mean, exactly? you get an error message or what? It would also be helpful to see what exactly you are trying

Comment: I meant to say it's not delivering the desired results .. for example .. it only replaces the ( #happy ) if I specifically search for " #happy " but it doesnt highlight all words/sentences that begin with a '#'

Comment: The search in Excel is rather limited, you could do this with formulas or VBA

Comment: How about google sheets? it supports regular expressions, could there be a way with that? :)

Comment: Yes that's possible with regex

Comment: Could you please tell me what would be expression? I can't figure it out on my own <3

Comment: `#\w+` should work you can test these things [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: If you can guarantee there will be a space after the hashtag, find & replace with `#* ` (with trailing space) should work.

Comment: Use `REGEXREPLACE`, You'll probably want something like: `#\w*`...

Comment: Try substitute()

Comment: @solarmike, unfortunately Substitute doesn't allow wildcards, so you'd have to know which exact substrings to replace and probably a whole lot stacked too. Or did you have another idea with it?

Comment: @JvdV So, I ended up with TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",""),"happy","")) which worked on "#happy 4 test 1" leaving just "4 test 1".

Comment: Cheers guys. #\w* worked flawlessly. Thanks for your time